# html/servlet Server side validation

Tags: java, html, servlets

So I'll be up front and explain, that this is for a class assignment. I'm not looking for exact code or anything. I have the vast majority of my project done, but I'm stuck on this aspect. I'll copy the text he wants us to do for this portion of the assignment.

**"3.   Server Side Validation – Code the NewCustomerServlet to validate the user has entered in values for all the form fields. If not, assign a message variable such as “Please fill out all the form fields” and display the message on the new_customer.html page."**

So the way the book describes to us, is by using a .jsp instead of a .html for the new_customer page. (The book utilizes a different project then what we are creating) I have the validation on the servlet down, that's not the problem. The problem is, when I try to use ${message} in an .html, it doesn't get the message variable from the servlet and just displays "${message}" in line in the html page.

as far as I understand it, I HAVE to use a .jsp to do what my professor wants me to do, even though we HAVE to use a .html for "new_customer"

How do I get a variable from a servlet from and html page?

side note: I've already sent an email to the prof, but in past classes, he takes a really long time to respond (online course) and I don't want to be scrambling last minute to implement something before it's due, so I'm nipping it in the bud.

Comment: Post your form data to the servlet and use ServletRequest on the server side to pull out the parameters.

Comment: I've posted the form data to the servlet and varified that each field is posted correctly. As far as the servlet request, do you mean something like, request.setAttribute("message", message);
If not, can you explain a little more? My problem is being able to display the message (in a non pop-up window) in the html page. Thank you!

Comment: @surlistyc: I think you're right. You cannot have a static HTML file with a dynamic part. The dynamic part requires you to use a JSP file instead.